# angularjs print html in a repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

righ now my code in html looks like this and it dont print the things i wanna print

```
 <tr ng-repeat="i in info | filter:search | orderBy: order">
  <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{i.username}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}{{i.edit_able}}</td>
  <td>{{i.min_amount}}-{{i.max_amount}}</td>
  <td><a href="<?php echo URL;?>ad/show/{{i.ad_id}}">View</a></td>
 </tr>
```

my angular code for edit able is

```
if(edit_able != false){
 $scope.info[i].edit_able =  [{html:'<a href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Edit price</a>'}];
}else{
  $scope.info[i].edit_able = '';
}
```

i wanna print out this in html and not as a html escape string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass HTML this way it has to be added to view by `ng-bind-html` and before it has to be sanitised with `$sce` but your problem is trivial really, you can just use `ngIf` to display the `a` tag only when necessary

```
 <tr ng-repeat="i in info | filter:search | orderBy: order">
  <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{i.username}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}<a ng-if="i.edit_able" href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Edit price</a></td>
  <td>{{i.min_amount}}-{{i.max_amount}}</td>
  <td><a href="<?php echo URL;?>ad/show/{{i.ad_id}}">View</a></td>
 </tr>
```